# How can I download all pictures I uploaded to Foodspotting?

Tags: export, foodspotting

I'd like to download all pictures I uploaded to Foodspotting: is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Foodspotting offers no option to download all pictures uploaded to Foodspotting.